# My phone gut stuck signing in with g-mail

Tags: samsung

So, I recently factory reset my J1 phone. It was twice. First bec. of the continuously switching on and off and then second, it was because I can't sign in with my existing g-mail account. I don't have any other solutions so last choice was to reset it twice. Now, I can't use and download apps. It got stuck on signing in with my existing account. It takes so much time. I even waited to sign itself in for the whole night but when I checkec it the next morning nothing happened. "The process com.google.process.gapps has stopped" and "Google Play Services has stopped" kept on popping out for like every 5 sec. I almost tried everything I saw on the net that can help me bug none of them actually helped with my prob. I just don't know what to do anymore. It sucks that I can't even use my phone. Please help me. I am hoping for your response. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cleaning app data for Google Play Services may help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've been trying to do that but every time I try, "Google Play Services has stopped" kept on appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution left to you is flashing the phone with a stock firmware using Odin (on Windows) or Heimdall (on Mac).

EDIT:

- Download the firmware from [here](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-j1/SM-J100ML/)(may need a registration)
- Unzip it
- Download Odin from [here](https://androidmtk.com/download-odin-downloader-versions)
- Power down the phone, press volume down + home button + power button simultaneously
- A menu should appear, press volume up button
- Open Odin
- Now connect the phone to the computer, you should see **COM** in blue (1), meaning the phone has been recognised.

  If not, install drivers which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/) - Download Kies and install it, will also install all drivers.
- Click on AP (newer Odin version)  or PDA (for lower Odin version) and browse to the extracted firmware folder. (2)
- Click on Start and wait till the end (3)

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The model number is SM-J100ML

Comment: Great. Alternatively you can grab the firmware from [here](http://www.gsm-file.com/files/smj100ml-1186)

Comment: Comments aren't great for step-by-step instructions but you're welcome to join us in [chat] for interactive help if needed.

Comment: @Dan Hulme Thanks, I'm on Android Stack Exchange app, there isn't  such option to start a chat. Would be great if they add it.

Comment: I doubt they'll add chat to the app, because the chat system is very tied to the web interface. The web interface to chat works on mobile, though.

Comment: how will I do that? sorry noob here

Comment: I learned how to do it. Done, thanks a lot again.